# RSA Signature Size Mismatch

Tags: c++, rsa, digital-signature, crypto++

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658728/rsa-signature-size), the length of the message signature is equal to the modulus of the Private Key, *aka* the Public Key.

I'm implementing a system that signs a message, and I have a size mismatch that I can't solve.
I use `crypto++`.

Here is the code I use :

```
/* Create RSA Keys */
RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 3072);
RSA::PublicKey publicKey(privateKey);
cout << ">> RSA Keys generated";
    /* Key Size */
    string spki;
    StringSink sSink(spki);
    publicKey.Save(sSink);
    cout <<" ("<< spki.size()<<" bytes)"<<endl;

RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer signer(privateKey);
size_t length = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
cout <<"MaxSignatureLength " <<length<<endl;
    SecByteBlock signature( length );
```

And the output is :

```
>> RSA Keys generated (420 bytes)
>> ServerHello sent (436 bytes)
   MaxSignatureLength 384
   RSA Signature length 384
```

Shouldn't the `MaxSignatureLength`, and the `RSA Signature length` 420 bytes long ?

Is the problem with the algorithm I use ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with crypto nor programming with encryption algorithms however when I was doing some research I found this website that may offer you some assistance. http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/index.html

Comment: @Eisen - Related, I think you are passing raw bytes to `Crafter`, and that might get you into trouble later if you have a message that spans multiple on-the-wire (or over-the-air) Layer 1 frames. Have you looked at [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf)? I think you can use them to frame a message inside `Crafter`. Or, you can ASN.1 encode your messages. Or, you can use something like [`BSON`](http://bsonspec.org/). Ina ll these cases, you will know the length of the message you sent and received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the MaxSignatureLength, and the RSA Signature length 420 bytes long ?

No. You are asking for a key with 3072-bits or 384 bytes. That's the limit on the size of the signature.

Each cryptosystem will likely be different in this area.

> ```
> cout <<" ("<< spki.size()<<" bytes)"<<endl;
> ```

This is the size of `{OID,n,e}` with the [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) framing or overhead. See your previous question [Sending PublicKey within packet payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32419626/608639) for what it looks like (in particular, the output of the command `dumpasn1 rsa-public.der`).

> ```
> cout <<"MaxSignatureLength " <<length<<endl;
> ```

This is `n - 1` for RSA, if I recall correctly.

> Is the problem with the algorithm I use ?

No, you are doing things correctly by calling `MaxSignatureLength()`.

---

```
 >> RSA Keys generated (420 bytes)
 >> ServerHello sent (436 bytes)
```

I'm just speculating, but it appears you appear to have design issues, too.

When you encrypt a message, like the `ServerHello`, you usually encrypt it under a symmetric cipher, like AES or Camellia. Then, you take that symmetric cipher key, and encrypt it under the RSA key. Finally, you send the pair `{encrypted symmetric cipher key, encrypted message under symmetric cipher}` to the other party.

In the system partially described above, you're only encrypting 16 or 32 bytes under the public key.

---

I *think* what you should be doing is using an Integrated Encryption Scheme to send encrypted message back and forth. For that, see [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) and [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme (DLIES)](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). ECIES operates over elliptic curves, and DLIES operate over integers.

Integrated Encryption Schemes have some very desireable security properties, like they are [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability). They achieve it by *not* allowing you to do some things, like reusing a security context, so the security is baked into the scheme.

You still have to solve the key distribution problem, though. That's a thorny problem, and we don't have a good, scalable solution.

And now you see why algorithm agility is important, and why you want that OID sent as part of the key during the handshake phase :)

Comment: Thanks for the more-than-complete answer ! but why does it says that the key is 420byte long ? Is it because the `RSA:PublicKey` contains more data (header/footer) than the *actual* key ?

You also said that I have a too long message. In fact, the message is the `Server Public ECDHE key`, which is 32-bytes long. Is that too long ? Or did you mean `ServerHello` when saying message ? In this case it's normal, I put the `rng` (16 bytes) before the publicKey. And 420+16 = 436 :)

Comment: @Eisen - I added some more information to the answer.